# this.setState in React is not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change the state of one component from another component and my state is not updating, I'm sending back the prop i want to update in my app component but this.setState doesnt work

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Header from './components/Header';
class App extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
    homeLink: "Home"
    }
}
onChangeLink(newLink){
    this.setState({
        homeLink: newLink
    });
}
render(){
    var user = {
        name: "sadf"
    }
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <Header changeLink={this.onChangeLink.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,document.getElementById('app')
```

And here is my header component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Header extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();
this.state = {
    homeLink: 'New Link'
 }
}
onChangeLink(){
    this.props.changeLink(this.state.homeLink);
}
render(){
    return(
    <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
      <button onClick={this.onChangeLink.bind(this)}>Change Link</button>
    </nav>
     )
   }
}
```

export default Header

Comment: Everything is working fine for me. The state is getting updated.

Comment: I agree @RITESHBANSAL . See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3aa6jmd4/2/

Comment: As @RITESHBANSAL said, there is nothing wrong in the current code, where are you trying to access the updated state value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let newPropValues = {
    root: event.target.value
};
this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, newPropValues));
```